# Interface function name case sensitive vb net

Tags: vb.net

I encountered an issue where I cannot call the same API function.
Previously, the API's interface function name is "IndexXML", but after they upgraded, the function name change to "IndexXml". 
I get this error when I call it:
"cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."

I know that vb.net is not case sensitive, but will it case sensitive in interface? Could not get any answer in google. Thanks!

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that this is a web service method?  That's kinda relevant.

Comment: I'm using WCF method to call it.